# "Dynamic" paths in React.js

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, frontend

I'm new to React.js, so maybe my question is dumb, but I've searched a lot for this information and I just haven't found it, so let's ask.

I've already learned the basics of `Router` in React, and I can create simple routes, as to say:

- My main page is in `localhost/`
- My about page is in `localhost/about`
- My contacts page is in `localhost/contacts`

You can see an exemple of what I'm talking about here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-example-8vcqu?from-embed. So, I know how to create a application like this.

But I didn't get a clue of how to create an routing system to give me the following:

- When the user select School A, React lead the user to `localhost/report/school_a`
- When the user select School B, React lead the user to `localhost/report/school_b`
- When the user select City Z, React lead the user to `localhost/report/city_z`
- When the user select City W, React lead the user to `localhost/report/city_w`

Considering that a school report presents the same layout for all schools, as a city report presents the same for all cities (what changes is only the data showned). Also considering that I have something like 3.000 schools to share reports.

All I wanna know is what topic I need to study to understand that (i.e.: dynamic routing?). You can assume I'm not getting the basics correctly, as I'm newbie to all this. Maybe I even not getting API concept correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: For sure it does. :)